what if a host is down
#!/bin/bash

SERVER_LIST=/path/to/servers.txt

while read REMOTE_SERVER
 do
ssh $REMOTE_SERVER "do_something_cool"
 done < $SERVER_LIST

what happens when one of the servers is down in this code?
i have been using hss to start apps in 25 remote computers, but i just ran into one being down and then hss looking for that host and it never moves on. so it's not optimal if one of my computers is offline.
will the above code move one to the next host in the server list if it comes across one that's offline? or is there an adjustment to make to this code to achieve that?

Add -n to ssh.

what option is -n?


will the above code move one to the next host in the server list if it comes across one that's offline?

Yes.
The issues I see here, are that, by default, it can take a very long time for ssh to fail when it can't connect and you're running everything in series rather than in parallel. Your script has NOT stopped, you're simply not waiting for long enough for this to timeout.
Regarding the first issue, this can be fixed with either...
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 $REMOTE_SERVER "do_something_cool"

or
timeout 10 ssh $REMOTE_SERVER "do_something_cool"

A very crude solution for running stuff in parallel....
while read REMOTE_SERVER ; do
   ssh $REMOTE_SERVER "do_something_cool" &
   sleep 1
done < $SERVER_LIST

(arguably there is another issue in your script - it doesn't collate/check the exit codes for ssh)

AFAIK the loop will continue after up to 5 minutes (or so). If you want to avoid the waiting you can make these changes in your code:
while read REMOTE_SERVER
 do
if (exec 3<>/dev/tcp/$REMOTE_SERVER/22) 2> /dev/null; then
ssh $REMOTE_SERVER "do_something_cool"
fi
 done < $SERVER_LIST

the if will check if the port 22 of IP is open. This does not mean you can be sure there is ssh daemon on it. I get the idea from this post.

You'd need to get the IP of the target host first. Always checking for SSH on the same IP is pretty useless.

@GeraldSchneider, the IP is in the variable, will update the answer :)

all great information. what i also just discovered was that i could do the ConnectTimeout in my controller .ssh/config file, so that i don't have to put in code every time.

@user1170119, this is another way to do the work :)
